# Fatal error applying Proguard to Retrofit2 and GSONAdapters

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit2, immutables-library, gson

I am trying to setup proguard on my app and I'm encountering the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getParameterized(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken; in class Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken' appears in /data/app/com.rw.crm.leads-1/base.apk)
                                                                                    at com.rw.crm.leads.model.response.GsonAdaptersResponse$ListResponseTypeAdapter.<init>(GsonAdaptersResponse.java:185)
                                                                                    at com.rw.crm.leads.model.response.GsonAdaptersResponse.create(GsonAdaptersResponse.java:36)
                                                                                    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
```

I am unable to come up with a proguard configuration that resolves this. This is what I have in the gson proguard file the moment:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.rw.crm.leads.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# To make the app compile
-dontwarn com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

# Why doesn't this work?
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.** { *; }
```

Edit: here are the relevant dependencies from build.gradle

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"

annotationProcessor "org.immutables:value:2.5.6"
provided "org.immutables:gson:2.5.6:annotations"
```

Comment: Show your dependencies from build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

By including the latest gson release in my gradle, I was able to resolve this error:

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`

This will be the fix until whichever library is using the older version (immutables or retrofit2) updates their gson.